# How to use shared preferences to populate a list of string items in a stateful widget in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-android

I want to use shared preferences to store a list of names of files that the user has created. Upon launching the app, I want to show a list of those file names by reading them from shared preferences. How can I read shared preferences data (from an async function) and populate the data in a ListView which is placed inside a stateful widget?

```
class ListCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListCard({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ListCard> createState() => _ListCardState();
}

class _ListCardState extends State<ListCard> {
  late List _dbList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _dbList = getDBNames().split(',');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _dbList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              _dbList[index],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The function to fetch the file names

```
getDBNames() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  var dbNames = prefs.getString('dbNames') ?? '';
  return dbNames.split(',');
}
```

This gives me the following error message

```
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance method 'split'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
```

How do I adapt my code to use Future?

On a side note, is there a way to read a list of sqlite databases on app launch and display the same in a ListView?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDBNames` is a Future method, you can use FutureBuilder

```dart
class _ListCardState extends State<ListCard> {
  late final future = getDBNames();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String?>(
        future: future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            if (snapshot.data == null) return Text("got null data");
            final _dbList = snapshot.data!.split(",");
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _dbList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Text(
                      _dbList[index],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}
```

Find more about [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). Also you can [save list on sharedPreference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences#usage)

also you can use `.then` and call setState but not looks good that way.